# In Perl, how to share a variable between subroutines, with use strict?

Tags: perl, use-strict

If I don't `use strict;` the following code works fine and prints out "alice":

```
assign_name();
print_name();

sub assign_name {
    $name = "alice";
}

sub print_name {
    print $name;
}
```

However when I do `use strict;` then I know I'll have to declare the variable before using it. I read somewhere I should use `our` instead of `my` to declare a global variable. So I had the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

assign_name();
print_name();

sub assign_name {
    our $name = "alice";
}

sub print_name {
    print $name;   # This is line 12.

}
```

And then I get the following error:

```
Variable "$name" is not imported at test.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 12.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Please help.

Comment: You should avoid using global variables. It will make your code easier to read, and avoid simple mistakes.

Comment: I also want to say, good for you user! Using `strict` is a good idea, and too often when new Perlers find that something doesn't work when using it, they are quick to abandon it. Good for you for asking why your code doesn't work and learning to do it correctly! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just declare the variable where both subs can see it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name;

assign_name();
print_name();

sub assign_name {
    $name = "alice";
}

sub print_name {
    print $name;
}
```

(There's no reason to use `our` here!)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where I should use `our` then?

Comment: You mean "when"? When you want to create a global variable, i.e. almost never; you always want to limit the scope of variables as much as possible. When you need to populate your package's `@ISA` for Perl for your packages `@EXPORT_OK` for Exporter is about the only two times.

Comment: I would add, you use a global variable (i.e. `our`) when you want the variable to be accessible from some other package. Nearly every time you might want think to do this, you would be better served rewriting the library using an OO scheme. (The reason `@EXPORT_OK` is global is because the `Exporter` module inspects it to determine which symbols to export, therefore the variable must be visible outside the package.)

Comment: @Joel Berger, my thoughts exactly

Comment: @JoelBerger Technically, you mean “scope” here, not “package”. One can trivially write code whereby code in two different packages accesses the same `my` variable, but for code in two unrelated scopes to access the same variable, it must be an `our` variable. Proof/Demo: `my $x =1; package A; print ++$x; package B; print ++$x`  versus `{ our $x; print ++$x } { our $x; print ++$x }`.

Comment: @tchrist, yeah, I always forget those details. I rarely have multiple packages in the same file and even then don't think to use that "feature". I would argue that its not a feature, and I'm sure I'm wrong, but I still always imagine that `my` should scope a variable to a package. Its a flaw in how I think about namespacing and pads etc.

Comment: ... I (incorrectly) always imagine that `package` starts a new scope.

Comment: @JoelBerger “Scope” and “package” are orthogonal concepts, and namespaces.  They are like two ships not passing in the night, on the other side of the universe from each other.

Comment: @tchrist, you are correct and I would do well to remember that, most notably so that I can avoid when I would stumble over that fact. I should remember to scope my `package` directives so that my expectations align with reality :-)

Comment: To clarify, there's no thing like "`our` variables". They are *package variables* like `$foo::bar` and [`our`](http://p3rl.org/our) creates a lexically scoped name for them.

Comment: @memowe, Not true. `our` variables are lexically scoped variables that are aliased to package variables. They are most definitely variables (an association between a name and storage).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is beyond the scope of your question, and ikegami's answer answers it nicely, still I think there is more to be said. If you have functions that are mean to change package-scoped variables, likely you could do better rewriting those variables as object attributes. In Perl we can do that using [`Moose`](http://p3rl.org/Moose).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{ # proper use of scoping, h/t tchrist

  package Person;

  use Moose;
  use namespace::autoclean; # recommended

  has 'name' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1);

  __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable; # recommended

}

my $person = Person->new( name => 'Joel' );
$person->name( 'Adam' ); # change name

print $person->name . "\n";
```

In this example we make a `name` attribute, we can set it during object construction, then change it or view it using accessor methods. The data that would have been global, in this case the name, is then contained inside the object's internal data. This allows different parts of your code to reuse that same logic without worrying about the state of that global data.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the global variable upper :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name;

assign_name();
print_name();

sub assign_name {
    $name = "alice";
}

sub print_name {
    print $name;   # This is line 12.
}
```

Comment: While this works, as ikegami points out, you really don't need to make `$name` global here.